# Aurelia Two-Way Binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to two-way bind in Aurelia and I can't seem to be able to make it work properly.

So I have create.html which has `selectedTimeZone.two-way="timeZone"`. I am trying to display the fact that it is working and binding by doing `<div if.bind="timeZone">Main: ${timeZone}</div>`. But this never works and the value `timeZone` is never bound.

In `time-zone-picker.html` it does seem to work there. I have `<div if.bind="selectedTimeZone">This is working! ->${selectedTimeZone}</div>` working properly.

Example

Main Template (**create.html**):

```
<template>
    <require from="../shared/components/time-zone-picker"></require>
    <time-zone-picker selectedTimeZone.two-way="timeZone"></time-zone-picker>
    <div if.bind="timeZone">Main: ${timeZone}</div>
</template>
```

**time-zone-picker.html**:

```
<template bindable="selectedTimeZone">
    <select class="c-select" value.bind="selectedTimeZone">
        <option>Select A Time Zone</option>
        <option repeat.for="tz of timezones" model.bind="tz">${tz.text}</option>
     </select>
     <div if.bind="selectedTimeZone">This is working! ->${selectedTimeZone}</div>
</template>
```

**time-zone-picker.js:**

```
import Timezones from 'timezones.json';

export class TimeZonePicker {
  constructor() {
    this.timezones = Timezones;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding the code below to match a response below. Still unable to make it work with the changes below:

time-zone-picker.js

```
import { bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';
import Timezones from 'timezones.json';

export class TimeZonePicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) selectedTimeZone;
  constructor() {
    this.timezones = Timezones;
  }
}
```

time-zone-picker.html

```
<template>
  <select class="c-select" value.bind="selectedTimeZone">
    <option>Select A Time Zone</option>
    <option repeat.for="tz of timezones" model.bind="tz">${tz.text}</option>
  </select>
  <div if.bind="selectedTimeZone">${selectedTimeZone}</div>
</template>
```

create.html

```
<template>
    <require from="../shared/components/time-zone-picker"></require>
    <time-zone-picker selectedTimezone.two-way="timeZone"></time-zone-picker>
    <div if.bind="timeZone">MAIN ${timeZone}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<template bindable="...">` only for html-only custom elements. In your case, you should do this:

**time-zone-picker.html**

```
<template> <-- remove bindable here -->
    <select class="c-select" value.bind="selectedTimeZone">
        <option>Select A Time Zone</option>
        <option repeat.for="tz of timezones" model.bind="tz">${tz.text}</option>
     </select>
     <div if.bind="selectedTimeZone">This is working! ->${selectedTimeZone}</div>
</template>
```

**time-zone-picker.js:**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-templating'; // or framework
import {bindingMode} from 'aurelia-binding'; // or framework
import Timezones from 'timezones.json';

export class TimeZonePicker {

  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) selectedTimeZone;
  constructor() {
    this.timezones = Timezones;
  }
}
```

**create.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="../shared/components/time-zone-picker"></require>
    <time-zone-picker selected-time-zone.two-way="timeZone"></time-zone-picker>
    <div if.bind="timeZone">Main: ${timeZone}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: So I did as you suggested above. Yet in my `create.html` I am still not getting it to bind over. `<div if.bind="timeZone">MAIN ${timeZone}</div>`

Comment: you should use `selected-time-zone.two-way="timeZone"` instead of `selectedTimeZone.two-way="timeZone"`. Mixed casing variables should be hyphenated in the html

Comment: that was what was missing. any reason why the dashes are needed there?

Comment: @allencoded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367953/pass-array-from-parent-template-to-child-template/36368441#36368441